# Static keyword usage php

Tags: php, static, static-methods

Let say I have a class like the following:

```
class MyClass {
  public function __construct($str) {
    // do some stuff including:
    $str = self::getIP($str);
  }

  private static function getIP($str) {
    return (bool) ip2long($str) ? $str : gethostbyname($str);
  }

  // other NON static functions ....
}
```

In the above scenario what is the advantage/disadvantage of having getIP static vs simply:

```
private function getIP($str) {
  return (bool) ip2long($str) ? $str : gethostbyname($str);
}
```

and calling `$this->getIP();` in the constructor (or any other method)

Context: I would normally do this without the static keyword but I have come across this a couple of times recently. Just wondering if there was any advantage of using static when you are definitely not going to use this.

Comment: What would you do if you want to call `getIP` from another static method of your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case there is no advantage or disadvantage.  However, a static method can be used by other static methods (perhaps some `public static` method).  Are you sure it's not called by another static method?

Technically any method that has no reliance on `$this` can be static as long as it conforms to its interface (e.g. if a parent method relies on `$this` but the child method doesn't, the child method should not be static).

Comment: yeah this is exactly what i understood. Just wondering if there was any advantage of using static when you are definitely not going to use `$this`.

Comment: @Lizard the advantage is that you don't need to create an instance of the object (i.e. you never need to use the `new` keyword to use that method).

Comment: @Explosion Pills - note it is private hence the confusion

Comment: @Lizard yes but there could be another `public static` method that uses this private one.

Comment: i did state in the Q that there were `other NON static functions`

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I'm not sure. Usually I use static methods because:

- It stores data in a static variable that I want accessible from several objects (sort of like a global)
- I don't want to have to create an instance of the object every time I call that method - especially if it's mostly called from outside.

For example, I usually create an App object that has many helper methods. One of these is `fetch_db`. Every time I want to connect to the database I just call `App::fetch_db()`.